# entity framework code only in release not cpt

Tags: entity-framework-4

how i can develop code-only EF application using release version of EF 4.0 not CPT.
release version doesn't include ContextBuilder and DbContext .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code first is not part of EF 4.0 realease version. It is separate project called [ADO.NET EF Feature](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4e094902-aeff-4ee2-a12d-5881d4b0dd3e) and it is only in CTP 4 at the moment.